# Java linux Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

Running on Linux, with IntelliJ IDE project, with Java 8.

`Java -version` gives me

`openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)`

If I `cd` to the folder  in which my fooBar.Java is, `ideaprojects/fooBar/src/com/company`, and run `java fooBar` the output is: `Error: Could not find or load main class fooBar`

Should I copy the .class in there? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to respect the package in which the class is. If the main class is in `ideaprojects/fooBar/src/com/company`, you need to start `java` from `ideaprojects/fooBar` and pass the main class as `com.company.FooBar`.

Comment: @Tunaki running `java com.company.fooBar` from the ideaprojects/fooBar folder provides the sam error.

Comment: That was a guess. Please refer to the linked question for all the possible explanations.

Comment: I've tried most of them by now, no luck unfortunately. I don't quite get it..

Comment: Solved - i had to cd to the /src/ folder instead